# Doctrine2 - One to many relationship with default value

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, default-value

I have a company object which has many bankAccount objects related to. However one company needs to have only one active bankAccount.

What's the right way to mark the active bankAccount in the company object?

In my current implementation I have added a OneToOne Unidirectional field called activeBankAccount that is initially nullable. It seems to work but is there any better way to do this?

```
class Company
{

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BankAccount", mappedBy="company")
 */
private $bankAccounts;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="BankAccount")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bank_account_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $activeBankAccount;

}

class BankAccount
{

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="bankAccounts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $company;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have two options. First is yours, it has the advantage that is easy to retrieve and or update the active bank account (only a single query or update is needed). Unfortunately, nothing prevents you to set an activeBankAccount that doesn't belong to the banksaccount collection. Another way is to add a property active to the bankaccount class directly. But this has the disadvantage for searching and updating, in this last case it will require at least two updates.